# Django TypeError: int() argument must be a not 'set'

Tags: python, django, mongodb, django-models

Сreated models:

```
class Teacher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Subject(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    teacher = models.ArrayReferenceField(to=Teacher)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.subject
```

while trying to add to the Subject in the Django Admin an error occurs:

```
int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'set'
```

Full traceback: [dpaste.com/3GWTC6P](http://dpaste.com/3GWTC6P)

Comment: Can you update your question with the snippet of code that you're using to add to the `Subject` model?

Comment: And the full traceback, please.

Comment: @Carlos Mermingas I add in admin panel

Comment: traceback is there: dpaste.com/3GWTC6P

Comment: What is `ArrayReferenceField` here? I could not find any `ArrayReferenceField` class  [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.1.2/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py)

Comment: I can't find the reason for this error. If you're using the default Admin configuration, I suspect it's something in "Djongo". You may want to post https://github.com/nesdis/djongo/issues or https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/djongo

Comment: It's method djOngo - django and mongodb connector

Comment: Yes, I'm using the default Admin configuration

Comment: Сould it be from the virtual env?

Comment: can you post your admin file as well?

Comment: @Rarblack there're imports and: 
admin.site.register(Teacher)
admin.site.register(Subject)

Comment: Just delete teacher field from model and admin page and run makemigrate and migrate again. See what happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What the error is trying to tell is that you cannot convert a set into an integer. I am assuming the error is due to this field `teacher = models.ArrayReferenceField(to=Teacher)`of yours and its return type is `set()`. You can get an index form the set and convert that into an integer:

```
a = set({1,2,3,4})
int(a.pop())
```

If you are trying to convert the whole set to an integer, first merge them and then cast to an integer.

```
x = set({'1', '2', '3', ''4})
y = ''.join(x) # converting set into string
z = int(y)
```

as stated above, make sure that you're not returning a nested list.

This is where **value** is casted to `int()` and the error raises:

```
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py" in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
```